# Batch processing in Mule 4

Tags: mule

I am performing a batch operation using batch scope in mule 4. I am using a Sfdc connector inside my batch step to query the Ids. The batch is happening in sets of say 200 and total 1000 inputs. I need to get all the 1000 Ids from Sfdc query outside my batch scope. I tried few ways to access the payload coming out of the batch step but failed to get the payload outside scope. I see that the payload is accessible only inside the process stage. Are there any ways to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tired using a Transform or set Variable to assign your payload to a variable?